# Unicode chars are printing, but not as expected

Tags: c++, unicode, printing, character-encoding

When i want a string containing a unicode char, i would normally do it with u8 before the string.
Since im making addons and gamemodes for a game, i usually need to use multibyte char set.

however, this project does not print unicode correctly, for instance, as a loading animation, i use a unicode char that is moved over periods. After applying some optimizations this no longer works.

```
case 1: game::functions.loadanim(XorStr(u8"•...... "), "Loading"); break;
```

but now, in place of printing the •, it prints â€Ç

all my unicode symbols have similar issues, project wide, some will actually print the unicode, but with unexpected results, when i try to append a degrees symbol, like this

```
XorStr("°");
```

it actually prints this

```
Â°
```

I have tried resaving all files as UTF-8 encoding, i have also tried changing encoding using the command line, if i dont use multibyte char set, it simply crashes, this was working fine before, and only changed after the optimization stuff in the property page, however, even after undoing all the changes in the property page, i still have this issue.

What did i break to cause this?

Comment: I believe your console doesn't support (the full range of) Unicode. I assume you are on Windows? The Windows console (`cmd.exe`) uses by default an old locale encoding. Even, switching it to UTF-8 doesn't make it much better. In this case, it does understand UTF-8 but prints every non-ASCII as `?`. My sad experience about this...

Comment: This sounds exactly the case, when i tried adding the u8 for the degrees symbol, it just crashed the game, i tried using L before the string, and i got a ? instead, im just not sure why it stopped working when i added optimizations in visual studio. And yes im on Windows.

Comment: Windows uses internally either ASCII (with locale dependent extensions) or UTF-16 (which was originally the UCS2). This can be seen in the Win32 API where a lot of functions exist with suffix A (speak: ASCII or ANSI) and a suffix W (speak: wide char). (Additionally, there is that ugly macro trickery which provides an identifier without suffix expanding to the suffixed function name depending on other macros.) If you claim that `L`strings (wide char string constants) worked but `u8` didn't (but crashed) I would _guess_ your game code expects and works with wide chars aka UTF-16.

Comment: That you got all these `?` with wide chars is an issue of the console but not your program. To check this, you may output into a file and view the file with a UTF-16 capable text viewer. (Notepad++ seems to support UCS2 which is partly identical to UTF-16 and might be good enough for a check.)

Comment: What happens if you submit `echo •` and `echo °` directly from your Windows console? Are the characters rendered correctly?